# Excel 2010 shows me a bad math result. Could someone explain me why?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

"Jeżeli" means "If" in the attached screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of my excel]

Comment: Most likely `5,3` is a number stored as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of error **usually** means that the value in **B481** is *Text* rather than *Numeric*.